# How to remove inaccessible screws from window handle?

Tags: screws

My window handles are defunct. The locking cylinder is missing from one, and the cylinder is loose and falls out of the one pictured. They are both locked shut permanently. Two screws hold it in place, one is accessible but the other is not. There is very little clearance to insert a tool to remove the bottom screw and the handle cannot be moved since it is locked shut. The clearance is about 5mm (shown in the second picture). Is there any specialist tool that could remove this screw?

[image: Handle]
[image: Handle clearance]

Answer (score 2):

It is by design that they are not easily removed while the window is locked. After all, why pick the lock when you can just unscrew the hardware....

You could have a locksmith open it.
Or, if these are to be replaced, you could drill the lock barrel out or cut the handle off with a grinder, oscillating tool, reciprocating saw or similar.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. If you're able to unscrew the handle, you're already inside the house. In any case, that has no bearing whatsoever on the task at hand. Moreover, a locksmith is useless because the locking cylinder is loose inside the barrel and no longer functioning: it just falls right out.